# What's the meaning of 娷?

Tags: translation, meaning, characters

While inputting PinYin's `shui`, I got the character 娷 among others. Neither automatic translators nor dictionaries gave me an accurate translation of it. I can identify the radicals 女 (female) and 垂 (to hang, to dangle; to hand down, to bequeath; almost, near). Maybe someone stumbled upon that character and knows what it means? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[娷](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=5A37)

> **“娷”字的【字海】释义**
> ㈠拼音zhui4。
> ①推委。
> ②饥声。
>
> ㈡拼音shui4。
> ①古女子人名用字。
> ②姓。

Two readings here. The first is zhui4, which comes with the meanings: to shirk responsibility/to blame others and sound of hunger. The second is shui4, which was just a character used in feminine names.